# Python: For loop with dictionaries (codeacademy example)

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a question about dictionaries and for loops. In this piece of code there is a dictionary, and I want to print keys and values from that dictionary separatly. From official documentation for Python I found that it's possible to use items() method, and that's clear for me. I can't understand why "print prices[x]" will give an output of only values, not key:value or just key. I'm running this code in Codeacademy website.

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}
for x in prices:
  print x # will print only keys
  print prices[x] # will print values
```

Thanks.

Comment: `I can't understand why "print prices[x]" will give an output of only values`Because that's how it works

Comment: you understand in your example that x iterates through the keys right? if prices[x] returned just the key then it it would just be returning the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is iterating over the keys in the `dict`.

So, first, you print the key. Then, you look up the value of that key in the `dict` with `prices[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `.items()`

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}
for item,price in prices.items():
  print item # => "banana"
  print price # => 4
```

It is a dictionary so you use the key to get the value.

```
prices["banana"] # => 4
prices["apple"] # => 2
```